# Forced execution of validation rules?

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule

Is there a way to force execution of all validation rules? Ultimately, I'd like to test an oppty against VR's, just as if you Edit/Saved, but without modifying its timestamps.

That way I can see how reported oppties are failing, without having to edit/change/touch live data.

Comment: best to do this in a sandbox

Comment: One ugly idea is to clone the opportunity and play around and then delete.

Comment: One thing to do is to use data loader to export records the meet the criteria. For example you have a rule where StageName = 'Pending' and SomeField = true, export records with those value. It takes a bit of time but you can get the records that fail each rule without modifying anything.

Comment: Combine Eric's idea and stick results in sandbox -- safest solution.

Comment: Can't we do it through the test class?Like setting seealldata=true. I know this is not a valid approach for writing test class but i don't think we are concerned about that here.

Comment: one idea it to perform an update of record without any modifications, but wrap it in Database.setSavePoint and Database.rollback  in any case. If there are update errors -- then check them. But I am not sure if that would not modify last modified date

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any out-of-the box way to do this. Maybe you can quickly do this with some anonymous Apex code:

```
List<Opportunity> failingOppys = new List<Opportunity> ();
for (Opportunity o : [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]) // Here you should select all fields that may cause validation
{
    Opportunity ocl = o.Clone (false, true, false, false);
    try {
        insert ocl;
        delete ocl;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        failingOppys.add (o);
    }
}
System.debug (failingOppys);
```

This code is non-bulkified so you may hit some Apex limits after 100 records or so. Let me know if this approach could work for you and perhaps we could come up with a bulkified/batched version of it. How many opportunity records are we talking about?

Comment: Should be `add` not `insert` in your `catch` block?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Database.SavePoint` and `Database.RollBack(SavePoint sp)`. Here is a [quick explanation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm) on how to use it